# Delimiter that consumes any quoted input

Tags: java, regex, java.util.scanner, delimiter

I'm reading from a file using a `Scanner` using the delimiter as follows:

```
.useDelimiter("[^a-zA-Z]+");
```

but I would like to know a way in which part of the file could be "skipped" quoted.

For example, if the file contained:

```
hello world "such a lovely day"
take a walk through the field
```

I would like the Scanner to return these tokens:

```
hello
world
take
a
walk
through
the
field
```

Comment: Please also show a few lines of the file you are reading

Comment: "such a lovely day" including quotes should not be written out by the PrintWriter along with any comments being placed in the file too i.e. 
/*such a lovely day*/

Comment: Wait, you want to skip comments, too?  You aren't trying to write a parser, are you?  Because this is not the way to go about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Treat `"..."` like it was one of the delimiter characters:

```
.useDelimiter("([^a-zA-Z"]("(.*?)")?)+");
```

---

Some test code:

```
String input = "hello world \"such a lovely day\"\ntake a walk through the field";
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(input).useDelimiter("([^a-zA-Z\"](\"(.*?)\")?)+");
while(scanner.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(scanner.next());
}
```

Output:

```
hello
world
take
a
walk
through
the
field
```

Comment: such a lovely day shouldn't be printed out at all
i.e. whatever resides within quotes or comments should be omitted from the output

Comment: @Ashley I misunderstood your question. See edited answer

Comment: thank you... just have to apply this to comments also....such a big help on my way to learning programming